# User authentication in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, authentication

I learned how to authenticate users in Django months ago, but I've since upgraded and am having some problems so it occurred to me this morning that I may not have been doing it correctly from the start so I decided to ask.

In my project's urls.py file I've got ^accounts/login/$ and ^accounts/logout/$ both wired up to the built-in login() and logout() views (at django.contrib.auth.views) and ^accounts/profile/$ is connected to a view I've written, called "start_here" whose contents are basically this:

```
def start_here(request):
    if request.user:
        user_obj = request.user
    else:
        user_obj = None
    is_auth = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        is_auth = True
    return render_to_response("profile.html", {'auth': is_auth,'user': user_obj,})
```

Now, "profile.html" extends a master template, called master.html, inside which is a "navbar" block whose contents are supposed to change if 'auth' == True (snippet below)

```
{% block navbar %}
            {% if auth %}
                <a href="">Link A</a>
                <a href="">Link B</a>
                <a href="">Link C</a>
                <a href="">Link D</a>
                <a href="">Link E</a>
                <a href="">Link F</a>
                <a href="/accounts/logout/">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
                <a href="/accounts/login/">Login</a>
            {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My problem is that when I log in, and it redirects to /accounts/profile, the navbar doesn't display Links A-F + Logout, it displays only "login". It doesn't work the way I expect it to unless I manually copy-paste the above block into profile.html. When calling render_to_response(), does the context I provide get passed to the parent template as well as the child?

Full source to master and profile.html: http://dpaste.com/hold/128784/
I don't see anything suspect in the code.

Comment: Could you provide the blocking code for master.html? It sounds like the problem you're having is with blocking. Also, to answer your question about the context: All the templates involved in rendering will see the context.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by blocking code? The entire contents of master.html?

Comment: In profile.html you have {% block navbar %}...content...{% endblock %}. You need to have a matching {% block navbar %}{% endblock %} in the template that this extends otherwise it won't show up. The fact that copying and pasting the block into master.html makes it work suggests that you may have mixed something up in these block tags.

Comment: Actually, I copy-pasted the block from master.html->profile.html not the other way around.

Comment: After like 3.5 hours trying to figure out what the heck is wrong, the problem went away when I restarted the dev server. Heh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is tangential, but Jim's suggestion to use RequestContext is so good I want to explicitly explain how to do it.

You can reduce your `start_here` function to

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def start_here(request):
    return render_to_response("profile.html", {},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

By using RequestContext, `user` is automatically added to the context. Instead of using

```
{% if auth %}
```

use

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the context you pass in render_to_response() is passed to the named templates and ALL the templates it includes or inherits from.

You should look into Using [RequestContext](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1)

### Another thing to check...

Just making sure:

your profile template begins with

```
{% extends 'master.html' %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make sure django correctly identifies users, you need to make sure it is properly enabled in your settings module.  specifically, you need to make sure that the `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware` modules are enabled in your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.  also be sure that `auth` is in your installed apps and you have run `syncdb` since enabling it.

If you have not taken the above steps, then django will not be able to detect when users have logged in and perform request setup properly.